# ReferenceError 'model' is not defined in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to write a basic mongoose application which has a schema. I had also created a model.
The code is as follows.` \

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
dbUrl='mongodb://localhost:27017/trial';
mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    createdOn:Date
},{collection:'users'});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var newUser=new User({name:'Simon',
    email:'simon@simon.com',
    createdOn:Date.now()
});

newUser.save(function(err){
    if(!err){
        console.log('User Saved');
    }
});


console.log(userOne.name);


mongoose.connection.on('connected',function(){
    console.log('Mongoose connected'+dbUrl);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error',function(err){
    console.log('Error'+err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected',function(){
    console.log('disconnected');

});
```

`
But when I tried to instantiate the model,
I'm getting the following error.

```js
var newUser=new User({name:'Simon',
                ^
ReferenceError: User is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jijebara\Desktop\IoT\Node+Mongo\m_app.js:12:
17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I am also sure that the connections are sure since the console messages in connection.on work properly.

Any ideas on how to solve this ..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import your newly created model. Just add this before using `new User`

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use model.

```
const User = ("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).